# What really is $0^0$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, limits

I have been reading online about this, and some consider $0^0$ to be equal to $1$, and others say it's undefined. I can understand the undefined part but why do some assume it to be one?

Comment: I believe some people assume it to be one since they remember that $a^0 = 1$ and forget the part that says $a \neq 0$.

Comment: It is undefined until you define it.

Comment: The most natural way to define $0^0$ is $$0^0:=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^x=1$$